# WPF CommandBinding XAML or ICommand?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am new to this so it might be a stupid question but..

I am looking into MVVM and the use of commands binding. 
When I read tutorials/resources I am told to use the ICommand interface and bind to that, which is all fine and dandy working.

But when I looked at some microsoft code example I noticed they don't implement the ICommand interface in the code but do something similar in XAML using

```
<windows.CommandBindings>
<cmd:CommandBinding x:Uid="cmd:CommandBinding_1" Command="New" Executed="DoNewCommand" />
<windows.CommandBindings/>
```

Now the question is, are both these methods basically doing the same thing except for the fact that one is using XAML or is there more going on, like me being completely off track?
Could someone shed some light on this?

Much appreciated!

Comment: both are same and what you are noticed is the XAML version of CommandBinding. [example](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/commands/using-commands/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are indeed the same, more info here http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/commands/using-commands/